# sqlite3.OperationalError: table users has no column named username

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Hello I cant figure out the solution for that problem. I searched on google but got no answer.
I'm new to db. so maybe its a dumb question :).

```
class Users:
    def __init__(self, tablename="users", userId="userId", password="password", username="username"):
        self.__tablename = tablename
        self.__userId = userId
        self.__password = password
        self.__username = username
        conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
        print("open database successfully")
        str = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +  tablename + "(" + self.__userId + " " + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
        str += " " + self.__password +  "TEXT   NOT NULL ,"
        str += " " + self.__username +  "TEXT   NOT NULL )"
        conn.execute(str)
        print("Table created successfully")
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    def insert_user(self, username, password):

        conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
        str_insert = "INSERT INTO " + self.__tablename + " (" + self.__username +"," + self.__password + ") VALUES (" +  "'" +username + "'" + "," + "'" +password +"'" +");"
        print(str_insert)
        conn.execute(str_insert)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        print("Record created successfully")


u = Users()
u.insert_user("yonatan@gmail.com", "123456")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here :

```py
str = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +  tablename + "(" + self.__userId + " " + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
str += " " + self.__password +  "TEXT   NOT NULL ,"
str += " " + self.__username +  "TEXT   NOT NULL )"
```

Indeed, concatenate `"username"` and `"TEXT NOT NULL"` will give `"usernameTEXT NOT NULL"`, without space between `"username"` and `"TEXT"`

You can see this if you execute the following query :

```py
conn.execute("SELECT * from sqlite_master").fetchall()
```

This gives you :

```py
[
    ('table', 'users', 'users', 2, 'CREATE TABLE users(userId  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , passwordTEXT   NOT NULL , usernameTEXT   NOT NULL )'), 
    ('table', 'sqlite_sequence', 'sqlite_sequence', 3, 'CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)')
]
```

Which is clearly a mess.

When you work with sqlite3, a good practice is to use the following syntax, which will avoid you a lot of space mistakes :

```py
conn.execute(
    f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {tablename}"
    f"({self.__userId} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
    f"{self.__password} TEXT NOT NULL, {self.__username} TEXT NOT NULL)"
)
```

Comment: yeah I got it, thanks I appreciate it a lot :)